# If $n\equiv (p-1)!-1 \ \mbox{mod p!}$ then the $p-2$ integers that precedes $n$ and the $p$ integers that succeeds $n$ are composite.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $p$ prime, $p>3.$ If $n\in \mathbb N\setminus \{0\}$ is such that $n\equiv (p-1)!-1 \ (\mbox{mod p!})$, then the $p-2$ integers that precedes $n$ and the $p$ integers that succeeds $n$ are composite.

I've proven that $\mbox{gcd}((p-1)!-1,p!) =1$. In fact, given any common divisor $c$, we have $c|p! $ and $c|(p-1)!-1$. Therefore, $c| p! - p(-1+(p-1)!)= p!+p-p! = p.$ Since $p$ is prime, it must be $c=1$.

Ok, now by hypothesis we have $p!|n-((p-1)!-1)$. Since we've proven that $p!\not| (p-1)!-1,$ it follows that $p!\not|n$.

What now? How do i proceed with those results? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You only need to know Wilson's Theorem for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you are going in the right direction. However, here is what you can do:

[1] The problem should be fairly easy for $n+k$ where $k\in\{-(p-2),...,-1,3,...,p\}$, because $n+k \equiv (p-1)! + k-1 (\mod p!)$, with $k-1 \in \{-(p-1),...,-2,2,...,p-1\}$ so $k-1|n+k$, and it is a proper divisor because of the size of it. ($n+k \ge (p-1)!-(p-1) \gt p $ for $p\gt 3$.) What is left are the cases $k=1$ and $k=2$.

[2] If $k=1$, then $n+k \equiv (p-1)! (\mod p!)$ so $n+k$ is divisible by all numbers from 2 up to $p-1$, and those are proper factors as in the previous case.

[3] If $k=2$, then $n+k \equiv (p-1)!+1 (\mod p!)$. It is a **well-known result** (Wilson's theorem, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) that, for prime $p$, $(p-1)! \equiv -1 (\mod p) $. This and the previous equivalence mean that $n+k$ is divisible by $p$, and again, by size argument, you conclude that $p$ is its proper factor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you be more clear why would $k-1|n+k$ in [1]?

Comment: Because $k-1$ is one of the numbers $2,...,p-1$ or $-2,...,-(p-1)$ and it divides itself and it divides $(p-1)! $.